# How to match columns, named as dates, that are between a start date and an end date. And return an average of those columns

Tags: r, date, match, gis

I have a dataset that has two columns, 'start_date' and 'end_date'. These columns have a range of dates spanning between 7 to 40 days. I then have approximately 50 columns, labelled with dates from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-22, with 16 day intervals. I want to create code that is able to find which of the columns labelled with dates lies between the start and end date. Then I want to return the mean of these matching columns in a new column in the dataframe, and then delete all of the columns labelled with a date.

Here is the dataset I have created:

```
    rm(list = ls())

library(lubridate)

# Create date columns with 16-day intervals (ensure correct order here!)
date_cols <- as.character(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2022-12-30"), by = "16 days"))  # Use as.character

# Determine the desired number of rows
num_rows <- 100  # Adjust this if needed

# Create an empty data frame with all columns (no changes here)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(date_cols) + 2, nrow = num_rows))
colnames(df) <- c("start_date", "end_date", date_cols)  # Assign column names for all columns

# Fill the start_date and end_date columns (no changes here)
start_date <- sample(seq(ymd("2021-01-01"), ymd("2022-12-30"), by = "day"), num_rows)
end_date <- start_date + sample(7:40, num_rows, replace = TRUE)
df$start_date <- start_date
df$end_date <- end_date

# Fill the date columns with random numbers (no changes here)
df[, date_cols] <- runif(num_rows * length(date_cols), min = 1, max = 2)

# Print the dataset
head(df)
```

Thank you in advance.

For reference, the dated columns represent rasters extracted for various points (rows). I want to match the data for the correct dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c(start_date, end_date), names_to = "dates") %>% 
  type_convert() %>%  
  summarise(across(value, ~ mean(.x[between(dates, start_date, end_date)])), .by = c(start_date, end_date))

# A tibble: 100 x 3
   start_date end_date   value
   <date>     <date>     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-19 2021-06-27  1.04
 2 2021-09-10 2021-10-18  1.44
 3 2021-05-22 2021-06-07  1.46
 4 2021-04-03 2021-04-28  1.65
 5 2022-04-11 2022-05-03  1.76
 6 2022-06-21 2022-07-11  1.55
 7 2022-09-20 2022-10-06  1.01
 8 2021-10-07 2021-11-01  1.71
 9 2022-02-07 2022-03-11  1.33
10 2022-01-11 2022-02-15  1.55
# i 90 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```